# Высчитать 100% высоты внутри блока рядом с фиксированным блоком по высоте

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Ребят, помогите советом по вертске.

Есть такая структура

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-box">шапка. 200px</div>
    <div class="content-box">контент. ОСТАВШИЕСЯ 100% (screen height - 200px)</div>
</div>
```

Нужно каким-то образом заставить браузер высчитывать 100% высоты блока .content-box не от размера окна, а он оставшейся высоты внутри .container, а т.к. .container растянут на всю высоту окна - значит высота .content-box должна высчитаться screen(height) минус .top-box(height).

Есть какойто трюк чтоб проделать такое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое что приходит в голову - `position: absolute`.
Стили для вашего примера:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 800px; /*Любая высота*/
}
.top-box {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.content-box {
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: я засчитаю этот ответ как правильный, т.к. оно делает то что я описал в вопросе, но я забыл указать что .content-box и все родители до body объязательно должны быть relative, т.к. в content-box находится связка: элементов Isotope плагина внутри mCustomScrollBara, и если хотя-бы 1 родительный элемент absolute - работать это дело не будет)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще я свою проблему решил таблицами

```
<div style="max-width: 100%;">
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="height: 200px;">
                    Я шапка, 200px
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 100%;">
                <div style="height: 100%;">
                    Я контент, растянут на всю оставшуюся высоту экрана.
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```